# Can't use class methods after initializing class

Tags: java

New-ish to programming java. I wanted to use my testing class to test my other methods to make sure everything was working as intended, but even after initializing the new class in my main method, I can't use the class methods in my Tester class.

```
public class PokerComparisonTests{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                Tester test = new Tester();
                testGetRank(test);
        }

        public static void testGetRank(Tester t){
                Card testCard = new Card(4, "C");
                t.assertEquals("test", 4, testCard.getRank());
        }

}
```

I'm trying to use "assertEquals" which is from my Tester class.

Warning from intelliJ:

> Static member 'proj3.Tester.assertEquals(java.lang.String, int, int)' accessed via instance reference

Comment: What is `proj3.Tester`? When it is a `static` method you call it by writing `Tester.assertEquals(...);`, but why does such a class exists when you have something like junit?

Comment: You wrote your own `assertEquals` method and Tester classes? As mentioned [Junit](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/) is what most people use

Comment: @Progman changing "t" to "Tester" worked. I didn't even know about junit, my professors haven't covered it, just stuck to what we did in class, will have to take a look at it then. Thanks.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between _can't_ and _shouldn't_. From what you describe you _can_ call `t.assertEquals()` but the warning says you _shouldn't_ do so because it's static. After all it's just a warning about a potential programming error: `t.assertEquals()` gives the impression that this method is bound to the instance `t` and that it could be overridden but that isn't the case. Using the class reference `Tester` instead of `t` makes this fact clearer.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for the explanation, it makes more sense to me now.